# Jruby - rails app and sidekiq on same jvm instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jruby, sidekiq

This a silly question, but couldn't find an answer. I'm running a rails app on jruby, and I use sidekiq to proccess background jobs. Do I really have to run sidekiq in another instance of jvm (is that what happens running bundle exec sidekiq) ?

Jruby is too much RAM consuming so this is not possible with my aws t2.micro instance.

Comment: why did you chose JRuby in the first place? Yes, just like CRuby, you need a separate Ruby VM to run `sidekiq` as a separate process.

Comment: Need jruby because app must be deployed on client`s server (which is also t2micro), so code should be somehow obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to high memory consumption your AWS microinstance will choke eventually. There is one way to have both `Ruby App` and Background process `sidekiq` running.

- Either you can boot another EC2 micro with `sidekiq`. You app instance and `sidekiq` server will share the same `Redis` instance. So, your BG processing wont be disrupted.
- Another way is to bootup a Heroku free dyno.
- Or you can move to `CRuby` or `MRI`.

hope this helps

Comment: if I use another instance, rails in the sidekiq server would be configure to access app server database remotely ?

Comment: Yes, you can also share the same app-database to multiple apps. You might have seen `DATABASE_URL` somewhere

Comment: in your case you will have to share `redis` instance as well; you can use services like `redistogo`